# Jest Test Component that Imports SVG with svg-sprite-loader

Tags: svg, jestjs

Hi I'm getting an error when running my angular unit tests through jest.

Here is the error

```
 Cannot find module '!svg-sprite-loader!node_modules/@my-package/brand-logos/laboratories/img.svg' from 'app.component.ts'
```

Here is my source code in my app component:

```
import '!svg-sprite-loader!node_modules/@my-package/brand-logos/laboratories/img.svg' from 'app.component.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'banner-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

Here is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: './tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.html$',
      astTransformers: [
        require.resolve('jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer')
      ]
    }
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/@angular-builders/jest/dist/jest-config/setup.js'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  testMatch: [
    '**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@core/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1',
    '@shared/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@ngrx)'],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/app/**/*.ts',
    '!src/app/**/*.module.ts',
    '!src/app/**/*.array.ts',
    '!src/app/fragmentTypes.ts'
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'json','svg'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['e2e','coverage', 'reports','/node_modules/', '/dist/', 'src/app/*.module.{js}'],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/AngularSnapshotSerializer.js',
    'jest-preset-angular/HTMLCommentSerializer.js'
  ]
};
```

How do i modify my config so that jest can use the sprite loader or mock it out?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was moving all my sprite loader imports into a file that we exclude from unit testing.  It's kind of a hack but it works.